# Проблема с Intent и Fragmentом

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Здравствуйте, скажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать Intent первого фрагмента во второй Фрагмент? И при создании `Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity()`, что тут нужно указать, ведь Фрагмент пока что не создан? Он создается после выполнения первого фрагмента. Создание происходит по очереди и динамически.

Comment: Как вариант держать данные в активити, в одном фрагменте getActivity().setData(Bundle bundle), в другом getActivity().getData();

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в итоге, может быть есть более простой способ?

Comment: Тема не актуальна

Comment: @xTIGRx, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так, если я правильно вас понял.

```
   Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
   fragment.setArguments(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());
```

Comment: Тоесть нужно еще один фрагмент создавать?Просто фрагемнты у меня динамически создаются.Просто тогда их будет 4, а не 3. вот мой код
http://ideone.com/SEhXgG

Comment: Конечно если бы я знал как можно обратиться к Фрагменту через ViewPager, чего в startAndroid я не нашел...тогда думаю проблема бы решилась, так как они все 3 создались бы и там к ним уже как к созданным Активити можно было обращяться...

Comment: @xTIGRx, объясните толком, чего вы хотите добиться, какого результата ждете от приложения?

Comment: 1) Есть 3 фрагмента,я их создал при запуске.

2) Теперь ввожу данные в первом фрагменте, и хочу передать через Intent данные во второй Фрагмент, 2 фрагмент выводит их.

3) 2 фрагмент должен существовать при запуске.

Comment: @kasto, ладно короч, использую немного гавнокода и создам через 3 отдельных класса, тогда проблем не будет. Спасибо за отклик